# Kendo UI TreeView - click on an already selected node

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview

I have a Kendo UI Treeview and the problem is that the select event does not fire when the user clicks on an already selected node. Is there any other way to do that besides triggering the event with jquery click on a class element?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid the answers is **no**. Not by design, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

Method 1:

```
<div id="treeview-left"></div>
<script>
    var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: [
            {
                text: "Furniture", items: [
                    { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                    { text: "Sofas" },
                    { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "Decor", items: [
                    { text: "Bed Linen" },
                    { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                    { text: "Carpets" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
        select: onSelect,
        dataSource: inlineDefault
    });

    function onSelect(e) {
        test();
    } 
    $(document).on('click', '.k-state-selected', function () {
        $("#treeview-left").data("kendoTreeView").trigger("select");
    });

    function test() {
        //Your logic comes here
    }
</script>
```

Method 2:

```
<div id="treeview-left"></div>
<script>
    var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: [
            {
                text: "Furniture", items: [
                    { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                    { text: "Sofas" },
                    { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "Decor", items: [
                    { text: "Bed Linen" },
                    { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                    { text: "Carpets" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
        select: onSelect,
        dataSource: inlineDefault
    });

    function onSelect(e) {
        test();
    } 
    $(document).on('click', '.k-state-selected', function () {
        test();
    });

    function test() {
        //Your logic comes here
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: I did it with the first method :D like this
$("#treeview").on("click", "li .k-state-selected", function (e) {
                var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),
                    node = $(this).closest("li")[0];

                treeview.trigger("select", { node: node });
            });